# htacces redirect and mask

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How would I redirect from the root folder to a sub folder and then mask that folder?

So instead of http://root.com/sub_folder

It would be just http://root.com

I have tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^root\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://root.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ /sub [L]
```

However, that does not work. Any help will be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify what I think you're looking for:

You want users who enter `http://root.com` with no trailing path to be rewritten silently to `http://root.com/sub`.

If a user directly enters `http://root.com/sub`, however, you want them to be redirected to `http://root.com`.

Any other path within root.com should be left alone.

The following two rules accomplish this. If you have more than one domain and only want this to apply to one domain, add your original RewriteCond in front of each RewriteRule.

```
RewriteRule ^sub/?$ http://root.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ /sub [END]
```

First rule redirects /sub with or without trailing slash to root.com. Second rule rewrites base domain to /sub.

EDIT: Per Jon Lin's comment, below, the `[L]` flag only stops the current round of processing and internal rewrites are sent through the rules once more (I always forge that part). So, you can terminate the second line with `[END]` instead, which stops all rewrite processing. The catch is that `[END]` is only available in Apache 2.4 or higher, so if you're on an older version something trickier will need to be done.

Comment: Those rules will cause a redirect loop.

Comment: How so? Only /sub is redirected in the first rule. After redirecting, the user loads the base URL which does not match /sub so the first rule does not trigger. The second rule is rewritten, not redirected.

Comment: Because the rewrite engine loops until the URI stop changing, the 2nd rule rewrites the URI to `sub`, then the engine loops, and it matches the first rule, which redirects the browser, then that request matches the 2nd rule, then the rewrite engine loops and the first rule gets matched, which redirects the browser, etc.

Comment: Thanks, Jon, I always forget that about the `L` flag as in my personal usage of it that particular scenario never occurred so I've always thought of `L` as the final step. Updated to `END` instead.